# How to replace a path in a file with new path using sed?

Tags: sed, filenames

I am using sed to replace a path in a file with new path. What is missing or not right here?

```
# sed -i `s|/$SPLUNK_HOME/bin/splunk|/opt/splunk/bin/splunk|g' filename
```

I get `>` with it.

Comment: Most of the time one wants to _add_ parametrization, not remove it... But what do I know?

Answer (score 5):

You are with the backtick (`` ` ``) opening a subshell statement which you are never terminating.  Make sure your quotes match.

The `>` prompt is the shell telling you that it is seeking more input for an unterminated quote by presenting you with the secondary prompt defined in `PS2`.

You want to use parameter expansion inside your script, so the weak quote (`"`) is the quote to use.

For example:

```
$ cat haystack
I found some straw in here!
$ needle=straw
$ sed "s/$needle/pins/" haystack
I found some pins in here!
```

Let's take a look at the difference between what happens when you use weak quotes (`"`) and strong quotes (`'`):

```
$ set -x
$ sed "s/$needle/pins/" haystack
+ sed s/straw/pins/ haystack
I found some pins in here!
$ sed 's/$needle/pins/' haystack
+ sed 's/$needle/pins/' haystack
I found some straw in here!
```

As you can see, with weak quotes, the parameter expansion for `$needle` takes place at the shell's behest *before* `sed` ever gets to see it.  With strong quotes, this does not happen, so `sed` is now searching for the regular expression `/$needle/`, which is "end of input followed by the string `needle`", which will never match anything, so no substitutions are made.

Comment: I understand why there is the > prompt. But what is missing or incorrect

Comment: I change and used this and got no error, but it didn't do anything in the file:
sed -i 's|/$SPLUNK_HOME/bin/splunk|/opt/splunk/bin/splunk|g' filename
#

Comment: Can anyone advise why "$SPLUNK_HOME/bin/splunk" didn't get replace with "/opt/splunk/bin/splunk" in the file, when I didn't get any error running this command?

sed -i 's|/$SPLUNK_HOME/bin/splunk|/opt/splunk/bin/splunk|g' filename

Comment: @user251227 variable are not expanded inside single quotes, change them to double.

Comment: Only 1 response so far? The command I ran below didn't give any errors, but it didn't change anything in the file of what I am trying to replace. Please advise.

sed -i 's|/$SPLUNK_HOME/bin/splunk|/opt/splunk/bin/splunk|g' filename
prompt#

Comment: Because you did not heed the information in the answer and above comments seemingly.

Comment: @user251227 `$` is special and means end of the line. By definition, there can't be anything after the end of the line, so the search string is never found. If you want to include the literal `$SPLUNK_HOME`, prefix the `$` with a backslash: `s|/\$SPLUNK_HOME...`; if you want to actually expand the variable change the `'`s to `"`

Comment: No luck... Can one of you put the exact command that would really work....please !!!
I am not really dumb, but am a basic scripter, so would appreciate your help. This is bugging me...

Comment: Example provided.